# R: Load a library into MyPackage

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm trying hard to find out how can i load a public library into a package i set up.

MyPackage is my own Package ant it uses the ggplot2-library to draw some curves. But i don't know how to make it happen. Once i tried to compile the package with Roxygen it's failed to compile.

Hier is the code:

```
#' draw.data
#' 
#' Function to draw the curve(y = f(x)) related to a given matrix xy 
#' @param xy a matrix with two entries
#' @return plot of the matrix xy
#' @author
#' @export
    draw.data <- function(xy){
      # ggplot-library import?
      library(ggplot2)

      x.lab <- "concentration [M]"
      y.lab <- "normalised luminescence [%]"

      data.temp <- data.frame(xy)


      my_labels <- parse(text = paste("1E", seq(-10, -4, 1), sep = ""))

      ggp.temp <- ggplot(my.data) +
                  #geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(x))) +
                  #geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
                  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
                  #geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(x))) +
                  scale_x_continuous(x.lab, breaks = seq(-10, -4, 1), labels = my_labels) + 
                  labs(title = "Graph", x = x.lab, y = y.lab)
      return (ggp.temp)
    }
```

Comment: Try `ggplot2::ggplot`, `ggplot2::geom_line`, `ggplot2::aes`, ...etc.

Comment: You're making a package? You should list ggplot2 in your Imports / Depends fields in the Description file.

Comment: @Dason That's exactly what i'm looking for... But i don't know how to do the import in the package.

Comment: Once you list it in the Imports / Depends field you don't need to import it inside your functions because it will get loaded for your package when your package loads.